# Which hbase version to be used with hadoop-2.7.1

Tags: hadoop, hbase, bigdata

I am confused which hbase version to used with hadoop- 2.7.1 or hadoop 2.6.0?

Answer (score 2):

HBase V1.2.x is now supporting Hadoop 2.7.1+ version.
I found this link, there is a chart of Hadoop and HBase compatibility. 
Have a look of it.
https://www.quora.com/Which-version-of-hbase-should-I-use-with-Hadoop-2-7-1